# How can I append values to a 2D array?

Tags: .net, arrays, matlab

I am new to MATLAB, and I can't fathom this from the documentation.

```
function GotData(sender, args)
    interval = args.DataBlock.TimeIntervalInMicroseconds;
    doubles = args.DataBlock.AsDoubleArray();
    x = 0;
    complexCount = length(double(doubles))/2;
    DATA = zeros(complexCount);
    for index = 1:(complexCount-1)
        realnum = doubles(2 * index);
        imagnum = 1i * doubles(2 * index + 1);
        complex = realnum + imagnum;
        x = x + interval;
        DATA(index) = [x complex];
    end
    disp(DATA)
end
```

I am getting an array of doubles from an event that fires in a .NET assembly. I'm splitting the array up so that each even item (in a 1 based array) is an imaginary number and each odd item is real. Then I create a two item array of the complex number and its interval. I want to then append this 1D array to a 2D array. How do I do that?

At the moment I'm getting an error: `In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.`. What should I be doing?

`interval` is 1, but can be adjusted.

Comment: what are the sizes of interval and doubles. What is the value of interval?
Try something like this:
>> d=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6]

d =

     1     2     3     4     5     6

>> c=d(1:2:end)+ i*d(2:2:end)

c =

   1.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 4.0000i   5.0000 + 6.0000i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `DATA` to be a 2-D array, you need to initialize it and index it as such:

```
% ...(your code)...
DATA = zeros(complexCount-1, 2);   % Initialize DATA to an N-by-2 matrix
% ...(your code)...
    DATA(index, :) = [x complex];  % Add the array to a row of DATA
% ...(your code)...
```

You can check out these MathWorks documentation links for further information about [creating matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) and [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

I was writing the same answer as gnovice, but he fired first. :)

In addition, if real data correspond to odd items and imaginary to even items, you should change the assignments:

```
realnum = doubles(2 * index - 1);
imagnum = 1i * doubles(2 * index);
```

Anyway I would vectorize the code to avoid for-loop:

```
%# ... code to get doubles and interval variables
n = numel(doubles);
realnum = doubles(1:2:n)';
imagnum = 1i * doubles(2:2:n)';
x = interval.*(1:numel(realnum)).';
DATA = [x realnum + imagnum];
```

Comment: Good point about vectorizing, but I think `interval` is a single value, not an array.

Comment: Actually, `x = interval.*(1:numel(realnum)).';` should suffice. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @yuk. MatLab is a different language to what I'm used to!

Comment: @yuk: You need to make the `realnum` and `imagnum` arrays into column arrays, otherwise matlab complains that CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.